# SASS output grouping selectors

Tags: css, sass, gulp

SCSS

```
.clearfix.scss {
    background: #000;
}
.container1 {
    @extend .clearfix;
}
.container2 {
    @extend .clearfix;
}
.container3 {
    @extend .clearfix;
}
```

CSS Output:

```
.clearfix, .container1, .container2, .container3, .container4, .container5 {
    background: #000;
}
```

How can I remove this grouping selectors.
Compilied by gulp.
Using this task:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('scss/style.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer(
            {
                browsers: ['last 15 versions'],
                cascade: true
            }
            ))
        .pipe(csscomb())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
        .pipe(connect.reload()) });
```

Comment: what is exactly the output you want? Are you in control of .scss file?

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the intended output of the `@extend` feature. It combines extended selectors in order to result in a smaller file output. You could try using a `mixin` instead.

SCSS:

```
@mixin clearfix {
  background: #000;
}

.clearfix {
  @include clearfix;
}
.container1 {
  @include clearfix;
}
.container2 {
  @include clearfix;
}
.container3 {
  @include clearfix;
}
```

CSS output:

```
.clearfix {
  background: #000;
}

.container1 {
  background: #000;
}

.container2 {
  background: #000;
}

.container3 {
  background: #000;
}
```